# Beacon UUID is different while scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am trying to find out the UUID of the beacon using altbeacon and the beacon getting detected using below code,

beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {   

        String uuid = beacon.getId1().toString();
        ...
}
```

But the problem is my actual beacon UUID is

```
E2C56DB5-DFFB48D2-B060D0F5-A71096E0
```

Where as the above code giving me the uuid

```
e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0
```

Basically both are same except the - symbol position is different on both UUID, this creating some problem on my application

What could be the issue?

**Edit:**

I can post more code if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID format returned by the Android Beacon Library is standard, and the one in the database is not.   Since you cannot change the database format easily, you can convert the string format with these lines of java code:

```
String uuid = beacon.getId1().toString();
String s2 = s.replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase();
String alternateFormatUuid = s2.substring(0,8)+"-"+s2.substring(8,16)+"-"+s2.substring(16,24)+"-"+s2.substring(24,32);
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but the above code will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to pull out all of the dashes from both, and convert them both to upper case and compare them.

Fix your current uuid to upper with no dashes (this uses `System.Linq`):

```
uuid = new string(uuid.Where(c => c != '-').ToArray()).ToUpper();
```

This will change your uuid from:

```
e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0
```

To:

```
E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E0
```

Comment: Actually I have to compare the UUID with database value through php and right now I cannot make the corresponding changes there, I think I have to follow as per your answer and put a `-` symbol on each 8 character  interval.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread this as a c# solution.  
Again, as a c# solution, you could remove the dash from your UUID, I think we could quickly write the same line in PHP:
uuid = (uuid_orig.Substring(0, 13) + uuid_orig.Substring(15, uuid_orig.Length - 15)).ToUpper();

Comment: Actually the upper case is not the issue as the this value is comparing with mysql database value, only issue is the slash. And at the moment I cannot touch the PHP, as it used by  some other application.

Comment: $newUuid = substr($uuid,0,13) . substr($uuid,15,21); // in PHP returns: e2c56db5-dffb8d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0